# Return which digit occurs the most times

Tags: c

I have to return which digit in a number occurs the most frequently ( though not how many times it occurs )

So far I can only get this, I don't know how to isolate the digit, only to show how many times each digit occurs.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int frequentDigit(int);

int main() 
{
    frequentDigit(123032333);
    return 0;
}

int frequentDigit(int arg) 
{
    int tmp;  int i;  int myArr[9] = { 0 };
    tmp = (arg < 0) ? -arg : arg;
    do
    {
        myArr[tmp % 10]++;   
        tmp /= 10;
    } while (tmp != 0);
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) { printf("\nThere are %d occurances of digit %d", myArr[i], i); }
}
```

Comment: `myArr[]` should contain `10` elements.  And, you don't have to isolate the digits, just go through the `myArr[]` once to check which one is `max`

Comment: ... and the for-loop should iterate from 0 ... 9 not 0 ... 8, i.e. increment the ceiling of `i` by one.

Comment: What should it return with non-unique solutions?

Comment: I don't know what changed, I just rolled it back the latest readable version.

Answer (score 1):

The array where you are storing the frequency of the digits, i.e `myArr[]`. Its suppose to hold the frequency of all the number from `0...9`. And since there are `10` numbers, you would need an array of lenght `10`.

```
int myArr[10];
```

Later, you need to traverse through the array once, checking for the max element, and saving the index accordingly, to find which number has occured most number of times.

To traverse, the `for` loop should go till `9`

```
for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
```

**Edited**

As someone commented, you can find the `max` value while you are computing the frequencies itself.

```
int max = -1, max_num = -1;
do
{
    myArr[tmp % 10]++;
    if( myArr[tmp % 10] > max)
    {
        max = myArr[tmp % 10];
        max_num = tmp % 10;
    }
    tmp /= 10;
} while (tmp != 0);
printf("%d", max_num);
```

Comment: Why do you need a loop for this?

Answer (score 0):

Its simple.  At the end of your code you have an array of frequencies, if you find the max of that you get the most common element

Just use a loop to find the max and print that:

```
int max = myArr[0];       // start with max = first element
int max_position=0;
for(int i = 1; i<9; i++)
 {
      if(myArr[i] > max){
            max = myArr[i];
            max_position=i;
      }
 }
  printf("\The max is %d occuring %d times ", max_position, max_position)
```

Comment: Why do you need a loop for this?

Comment: The value of the number does not matter, we are just trying the number which occurs the most frequently. It doesn't have to be the largest number

Comment: The code should be `max = array[i];` and as OP says, it does not answer the question.

Comment: @JohnSmith  Maybe this code is to find the max frequency that is stored in array .

Comment: You are finding the largest number, not the most frequent.

Comment: This is an array of frequencies. At the end of the OPs question, he gets an array of frequencies. If you find the largest number from the array of frequencies you will get the most common number

Comment: I think you are mistaken. When I run OP's program, it tells me how many times each digit occurs, including `There are 5 occurances of digit 3` so plainly, as `5` does nor occur in the array, he has counted the number of threes. Your answer only works because `3` happens to be the largest number as well as the most frequent.